# Why can't the drag image element be scaled

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

In the code below, the background styles are applied, but the scale transform doesn't work on the overlay. But it's being added to the overlay since the DOM item beside it is scaled down, but the overlay image isn't. How can I scale the drag image as well?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title>Examples of DataTransfer.{types,items} properties</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width" />
  <script>
    function dragstart_handler(ev) {
      const overlay = document.getElementById("box1")?.cloneNode(true);
      const coords = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (overlay) {
        overlay.style.transform = "scale(0.5,0.5)"; // <-- this doesn't apply to the drag image
        overlay.style.backgroundColor = "skyblue";
        overlay.id = "overlay";
      }
      document.body.appendChild(overlay);
      ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(overlay, coords.width/2, coords.height/2);
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.dataset.id || "");
      ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
    }

    function dragend_handler(ev) {
      const overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
      if (overlay) {
        overlay.remove();
      }
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <div
      id="box1"
      ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event);"
      ondragend="dragend_handler(event);"
      draggable="true"
      style="
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 2em;
        margin: 1em;
        display: inline-block;
      "
    >
      Item
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```